# Plot Materials Structure - Pymatgen

Tags: python, plot, vtk

Is there anyone ever use pymatgen? 
When I visit the [official site of pymatgen](http://pymatgen.org/). I saw the quick start tutorial. I think this package is very nice. My question is I want to plot materials structure look likes in this figure.
[image]

I got an information from that site, to plot structures

```
#Visualize a structure. Requires VTK to be installed.

pmg view filename
```

I've download VTK. But I do not know, how to use it. I could not understand clearly.

Comment: Have you already installed pyVTK and pymatgen? Which OS are you using?

Answer (score 3):

Me and my colleages use pymatgen a lot but we add an external package to display pymatgen structures in jupyter notebooks called nglview.

```
conda install -c conda-forge nglview
```

to display the structure_to_show (a pymatgen structure object):

```
    import nglview as nv

    view = nv.show_pymatgen(structure_to_show)
    view.add_unitcell()
    view
```

this can handle very large structures very fast

Answer (score 1):

Please install vtk with python support, depending on your python version on the machine.

For python 3

```
conda install -c clinicalgraphics vtk
```

For python 2

```
conda install -c anaconda vtk
```

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the **nglview** solution by **[seten](https://wiki.fysik.dtu.dk/ase/_modules/ase/atoms.html)** - it basically uses the ASE source code

```
return show_ase(AseAtomsAdaptor().get_atoms(struct))
```

You might therefore immediately use ASE for plotting pymatgen structures.